# How to save results page number, while going through a tag?

Tags: support, new-nav

In the new Navigation/Tabs feature, when I list all the questions tagged with `Android` according by number of votes, the URL on top only says

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=votes

So if I'm going through this list, and I want to save my current progress on say page 10, the url on top still doesn't reflect this and I can't continue the next day from here, since page refreshed will take me to the start of the search result.

How can I save a URL, that can either save the result number, or take me directly to a particular number on search results?

Comment: No repro, when I click on "3", I get the slug `?page=3` appended to the URL.

Comment: @CodyGray Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using the new Tabs feature.

Comment: This also breaks the back button. It's incredibly annoying and why I switched back to the old layout.